# While writing htaccess code my page again load in body

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to create seo url for my website. Actually i am aware of how to write code through htaccess. i found many tutorials but not helps me.i also write a code inside  but not working. to remove php extension  first code works successfully.while writing next code for seo url its load my whole page again in body. please help me

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  Options +FollowSymLinks

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule  ^**photos**/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*) /photos.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why are you repeating three lines in your second code?

Comment: Actually i did copy paste from tutorials

Answer (score 0):

No need of multiple "`RewriteEngine On`" statement. Did you try with below lines?

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule  ^**photos**/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*) /photos.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
  Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: its give me Internal Server Error and my website in subdomain